# how to change the TextView background color to initial value

Tags: android, textview

after I set the TextView backgroundColor to whatever I want.

Fri2030 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFri2030);
Fri2030.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

how to clean up the TextView backgroundColor if I don't want any color on it and initialize it. (don't wanna cover by other colors)

thx for the help!!

Comment: Ambiguous question. What exactly do you want to do? You want to add colors or not. If not just comment that code

Comment: When do you want to clean up textview background color? clicking on textview or what?
If you want you can use selector in the xml

Comment: @Rashmi.B: He want to restore default color if something happen dynamically.Commenting code is not solution.

Comment: if(condition){ set this color } else if(condition) { set this color } Thats all I can possibly tell. I am still not clear what he wants

Comment: if(condition){set initial color that we do not know,first we have to find which default color used in TextView background}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this help you...once store all these value and later on when you need it
then use them---

```
        TextView text=new TextView(this);
    text.getCurrentHintTextColor();
    text.getCurrentTextColor();
    text.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```